# Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, vstest

I'm trying to configure Test release pipeline on Azure DevOps. I'm using my own agent pool so I have to use Visual Studio Test Platform Installer before run Visual Studio Test. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

My configuration:

> Server - Azure Pipelines
>
> Agent - Private
>
> Test platform installer version (Latest Stable)
>
> Test platform version (Installed by Tools Installer)

Test Release result:

[image]

Release config:
[image]

Comment: Since it's a private agent, you have a few additional details to work out. 1) Does your machine have access to the Internet to download from nuget.org? and 2) maybe the version of nuget on the machine needs to be updated?

Comment: hmm, It looks like my private machine does not have access to nuget.org, but I will check it.